# SQL Developer 4.2.0 will not launch on Mac running Catalina OS

Tags: macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer 4.2.0 was installed and working on this Mac when it was running Mojave.  The user reports that after updating to Catalina it stopped working. However, the user is not sure if it stopped working immediately after Catalina. SQL Developer will start to load and then disappears. I have uninstalled / installed SQLDEV and that didn't fix the issue. If I connect remotely as an admin (in the background), SQLDEV will launch successfully.  I have tried granting full disk access to both the app and /bin/bash and nothing has helped so far. I feel like the uninstall is not getting rid of all components. Any suggestions to help resolve this are appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Without knowing anything specific about your problem, this would clearly imply that SQL Developer 4.2.0 is 32 bit.  Apple decided (for you)  that you didn't need 32 bit support anymore as of Catalina.

Comment: 4.2 is really really old, tell your user they should upgrade.

Comment: Some sqldev on mac tips here https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/java-mac-sqldev/

Comment: SQL Developer launches fine when I connect to the Mac remotely.  It won't load when the end user launches it.  So I think that rules out the 32 bit issue.

Comment: Issue resolved:  removed hidden directory structure user/.sqldeveloper and SQL Developer now launches without issue.